# Vapor - Liquid Equilibrium (VLE)

Tags: thermodynamics, chemical-engineering

Most fundamental equation for VLE is $$ \mu_i^L = \mu_i^V $$

It states that for every component chemical potential must be equal in both liquid and vapor phase at equilibrium. However, in my thermo textbook, this equation is derived for isolated systems while usually when dealing with VLE, systems are closed since heat is usually exchanged with surroundings like in distillation for example. Does this equation hold also for closed systems and if so how can it be derived?

Comment: The question rather is, if the system is in equilibrium or not. Boiling liquid definitely is not. More closely the system approaches equilibrium, more closely the relation of respective ch.p. approaches equality.

Comment: That isn't the question. Question is what is written in the description.

Comment: In fact, it is. Is the closed system in equilibrium or not? If not the equation can be true just approximately, depending on nature and extend of the deviation.

Comment: And if it is in equilibrium, it is functionally equivalent to isolated system, as energy exchange is zero.

Comment: We are dealing with closed system at equilibrium. Why should energy exchanged be zero at VLE in closed system? We can have water vapor in equilibrium with liquid and add heat (latent heat)to the system which will make liquid evaporate, but this won't change the fact that chemical potential off the water in two phases is the same.

Comment: If you add to system in eq. heat dQ, liquid will have  ch.p. increased wrt vapor by dmu, until dn of liquid evaporates and both phases have the same ch.p. again. The more macroscopic this heat addition or rate is, the bigger difference of ch.p. of both phases will be. Ch.p. difference is the power leading to phase changes.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Adding heat can change internal energy and create some work by the first law. I am not sure how would it affect chemical potential of phases or how to justify that liquid's chemical potential will increase as you say?

Comment: What do you think the difference between an "isolated" and a "closed" system is?